# Cordova/Phonegap ORM?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Are there any ORM javascript projects compatible with Cordova, like [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/)? I did a google search, github search, searched here, and couldn't find any.

If not, maybe it's time to start one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This old but I stumbled upon it so others might too... what ended up working for me was using the [Cordova SQLite plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) for a db with no size limit and the [Persistence.js](https://github.com/coresmart/persistencejs) ORM to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but there is also [Persistence.js](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs) which I actually ended up using. It has it's own drawbacks, but every ORM does.

It would actually use the HTML5 storage on the phone. This is limited to 5mb per the specification, but obviously individual vendors may not enforce or follow this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an Open Source Framework, known as Siminov Hybrid, it provides ORM for both Android Native (Java) and Web (JavScript). It is easily configurable which works for both Native and Web at same time.

Works with Phonegap and later it will be support on other frameworks also.

http://siminov.github.io/android-hybrid

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why there is no official ORM for sqlite with cordova though it is very required !

Anyway as time of writing this , you have the below option : 
1- typeorm with angularjs2 ( they promised to provide support for sqlite ) 
2- ionic2-orm it is a fork of the previous point , however it look like there is no support till now
3-ionic2-orm2 which is a fork of the previous point also ( duh.. ) you can access it on this one https://github.com/sidneycorreia/ionic-orm

4- the best option up to this point is pouchdb check this one https://pouchdb.com/